# Как узнать какой тип данных возвращает функция?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть такой вопрос, возможно ли как-то узнать, какой тип данных **возвращает функция**.

Например есть функция:

```
def foo():
    return 'bar'
```

Есть ли какие-то варианты, помимо визуального, чтобы узнать что это тип string?
Если с переменной можно использовать type(x), то возможно ли провернуть что-то подобное с функциями?

Comment: `type(foo())` .

Comment: А если разные типы возвращает? `return "OK" if condition else 42`

Comment: @MBo Выходит что в зависимости от условия функция будут возвращать тот или иной тип данных. Ну это я думаю можно отобразить в подсказках типов: -> str | int.

Comment: В общем случае функция может возвращать абсолютно любой тип, например `def foo(s): return eval(s)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def foo():
    return 'bar'
print(type(foo()))
```

Вот так должно работать

Comment: Да, действительно. Когда сам тестировал забыл про скобки и передавал ссылку на функцию.